# How does "request" represents an instance of HttpServletRequest in a JSP?

Tags: java, jsp

We often do the following inside the scriptlet:

```
<%
   request.getCookies();
%>
```

Can anyone tell me, what is `request` here? I know it represents `HttpServletRequest` but I haven't declared it. I just do not understand this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`request` is a variable of type `HttpServletRequest` that is declared and initialized for you in the code generated by the servlet container when the JSP code is transformed into a Servlet class and compiled, it also known as one of **[implicit objects](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_implicit_objects.htm)** in JSP.

Note that using scriptlets in JSP is bad practice for years. You should learn JSP EL, the JSTL, and choose an MVC framework that allows separating the Java code for the pure markup-generation code.

Comment: The JSP EL is the JSP expression language. It's a language that you use inside JSPs. You can't skip JSPs.

Comment: Yes, forget they exist. They shouldn't be used.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files/3180202#3180202 and http://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info